# How does derivative of a squared function work?

Tags: calculus

I was working through a physics problem related to magnetic flux, but was confused at the math the solution uses. I understand up till the last line:

$
c=1.65-.12t\\
A=c^2/4\pi\\
\Phi_B=BA=(\frac{B}{4\pi})c^2\\
|\varepsilon|=|\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}|=(\frac{B}{2\pi})c|\frac{dc}{dt}|
$

I'm unclear of the exact steps that allow this to go from $\frac{B}{4\pi}\frac{dc^2}{dt}$ to $(\frac{B}{2\pi})c|\frac{dc}{dt}|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\epsilon|$ is the magnitude of the derivative.

$$\left|\epsilon\right|=\left|\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}\right|=\left|\frac{B}{2\pi}\frac{d}{dt}c^2\right|=
  \frac{B}{2\pi}\left|\frac{d}{dt}c^2\right|=\frac{2B}{2\pi}c\left|\frac{dc}{dt}\right|$$

Here we've used the fact that $\frac{d}{dt}c^2$ = $2 \cdot c \frac{d}{dt}c$.  This is the chain rule.
Note that the solution above assumes that $c$ is positive.  Based on the definition of $c$, this will only be true for values of t that are small enough.  One could easily include $c$ inside the magnitude, and the solution will be valid for all time.

Comment: But doesn't $\frac{d}{dt}c^2=2c$ for the chain rule?

Comment: @DennisHodapp In this problem, $c$ is a function of time.  Let's denote it more clearly as $c(t)$.  So the question is, what is $\frac{d}{dt}\left( c(t) \right)^2$?  We use the chain rule.  $\frac{d}{dt}\left( c(t) \right)^2=2c(t)\frac{d}{dt}c(t)=2c(t)c'(t)$

Comment: Ah I understand now. My mistake was thinking of c as a variable instead of a function. Thanks!